# Install pep 518 build system requirements only (to build sdist)

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

[PEP 518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) introduced the `pyproject.toml` file, as well as a section describing the tools needed to build:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel", "numpy>=1.13"]
```

Here, I'm telling the build system (implicitly setuptools) that I need these three requirements installed before I can run the build.  (And yes, I actually do need numpy as part of the *build* process.)

When I run `pip wheel`, it knows to look for this section in this file, install the requirements, and then build the wheel.  But pip has no way to create an `sdist` distribution (and its maintainers [seem reluctant](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6041) to add one), so I need to run `python setup.py sdist`.  And that's where the problem comes in: setup.py doesn't know it needs numpy, and the build fails.

Is there a standard way to just install the requirements, and then build an sdist?  In particular, pip has moved toward build isolation, so can this be done with isolation?  Failing that, I could create my own environment for some isolation; then, what's the best way to install the requirements in some environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is with the pypa project [pep517](https://pypi.org/project/pep517/) (though the module is marked "experimental")

here's a sample dist with a special dependency that I tried:

```py
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup
import astpretty
setup(name='wat', version='1')
```

```
# pyproject.toml
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel", "astpretty"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

```
$ python -m pep517.build --source .
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.1; however, version 20.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/x/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
running egg_info
creating wat.egg-info
writing wat.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to wat.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to wat.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'wat.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'wat.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'wat.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running sdist
running egg_info
writing wat.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to wat.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to wat.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'wat.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'wat.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
warning: sdist: standard file not found: should have one of README, README.rst, README.txt, README.md

running check
warning: check: missing required meta-data: url

warning: check: missing meta-data: either (author and author_email) or (maintainer and maintainer_email) must be supplied

creating wat-1
creating wat-1/wat.egg-info
copying files to wat-1...
copying pyproject.toml -> wat-1
copying setup.py -> wat-1
copying wat.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> wat-1/wat.egg-info
copying wat.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> wat-1/wat.egg-info
copying wat.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> wat-1/wat.egg-info
copying wat.egg-info/top_level.txt -> wat-1/wat.egg-info
Writing wat-1/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'wat-1' (and everything under it)
$ ls dist/
wat-1.tar.gz
```

Comment: Using pip517.build is deprecated and it suggests using  https://pypi.org/project/build/ instead. See my other answer.

Answer (score -1):

You want [build](https://github.com/pypa/build). It is project under the Python Package Authority (PyPA) that was created specifically to build PEP 517 packages.

It will build both a wheel and an sdist. However you can tell it to only build an sdist as well.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33211772)